# Single document storing multiple child class objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoDB Spring data in my application. 
My java class looks like this:

```
Class Mongo{
    private BaseClass bc;
    private String id;
}

Class BaseClass{
    private String baseName;
}

Class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass{
    private String childName;
}

Class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass{
    private String childContent;
}
```

I save the Mongo object in a document using mongoTemplate.insert() method.
The instance bc can store an object of childclass1 or childclass2
The problem occurs while fetching the data from the collection.
The mongoTemplate.find() will always return the BaseClass object.
Even type casting it to the corresponding child class throws a ClassCastException.

Should I be using separate collection for each child class MongoChild1, MongoChild2 and so on to avoid this issue ?

Comment: Can you write a test to reproduce the problem?  That would help us track down a solution.